# Как сравнить массивы с одинаковыми названиями?

Tags: php

В общем есть

```
$nees = array();
    foreach($json as $row)
{
    $nees[$row[name]]=$row[value];
}
```

и второй такой же, но теперь как сравнить name с другим списком в котором name==name?
пробывал так:

```
foreach($nees as $kk => $kkz)
{
    foreach($nees2 as $kk2 => $kkz2)
{
    if($kk==$kk2){
    echo $kkz."\r";}
}
}
```

Comment: Сложно понять когда такой пример, если добавите примеры массивов и что хотите чтобы получилось - вот тогда было бы понятно всё.

Comment: получается `if($kk==$kk2){ echo $kk;  echo $nees[$kk]; echo $nees2[$kk];}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у тебя есть 2 массива с одинаковой структурой, т.е. name=> значение, то существует и следующий вариант (их много)

```
foreach($nees as $name=>$value){
    if (isset($nees2[$name])){
        //пишешь то что ты хочешь сделать например
        echo $name.','.$value.','.$nees2[$name];
    }
}
```

(Либо я дурак, либо лыжи не едут)

Comment: спасибо большое) работает)

Comment: Отметь что тебя ответ устроил, а то подумают что нибудь)